# Nested resources and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing an Utility invoicing app and a Customer has many readings. Readings belong to a customer.

In my routes.rb

```
resources :customers do 
    resources :readings
end
```

I would love the creation of a new reading to happen in a specific customer's view and therefore in my customers controller

```
def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @reading = Reading.new(:customer => @customer)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
end
```

Then in my Customer's show view, I add the form for adding a new customer's reading as below

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer,@reading do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :customer, :value => @reading.customer.name %>
   <%= f.input :date_of_reading, :as => :date %>
<% end %>
```

However, on accessing localhost:3000/customers/1, i get a no-method in Customers#show error for the piece of code I added for adding a reading. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form expects an array, but you are passing two separate objects. Change:

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer, @reading do |f| %>
```

to:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@customer, @reading] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thank you, that has worked. One more thing though, when trying to retrieve the current Customer's name to populate the reading's form '<%= f.input :customer, :value => @reading.customer.name %>' The value returned is an object like #<Customer:0x007fa006b39ec8> How can i retrieve the name itself?

Comment: @zurik, I don't know how to fix that. It's because you do `f.input :customer` and `customer` is an object. This is a form for readings. I don't think you should be editing a customer's name here. A customer's name should be edited via `/customers/1/edit` instead. In my opinion at least. I would consider only displaying the name of the customer. This is the customer show action after all.

Comment: No problem then, I actually want to show the current customer's name in the input field for the reading form as the default. However, let me figure out how to do that